# Insert Output of a Query into a table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created which calculates the values needed for payslip, I want to now use the output of this query to append to the end of my "Paylsip" table so it keep record of Past payslip for employees. Let me add, this is for a project and not professional, IRL I would just use a paid software.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Payslip Calc].EmployeeID, DateSerial(Year(Date()),
[WorkMonth]+1,0) AS [Date],
[Payslip Calc].WorkMonth,
[Payslip Calc].PayCode,
Sum([Payslip Calc].HoursWorked) AS [Sum Of HoursWorked], 
Sum([Payslip Calc].Balance) AS [Sum Of Balance], 
Sum([Payslip Calc].TotalAmt) AS [Sum Of TotalAmt], 
Sum([Payslip Calc].OvertimePay) AS [Sum Of OvertimePay]
FROM [Payslip Calc]
GROUP BY [Payslip Calc].EmployeeID, DateSerial(Year(Date()),
[WorkMonth]+1,0), [Payslip Calc].WorkMonth, [Payslip Calc].PayCode;
```

That is my query which does the calculates.

I want to insert this into a table called "Payslips" which has a unique Payslip autonumbers in its first column.

Is this even possible?

Comment: In the query designer, change the query from a _select_ query to an _append_ query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO PaySlips (EmployeeID, Date, WorkMonth, . . .)
    <your query here>
```

That is, list the columns that you want to insert explicitly.